# Custom package installation fails

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I want to allow my Jupyter notebooks to import custom Python modules.
To this end, I attempt to install a package whose modules I can import, for example, through `from projectmnemonic import test`.

My library's source code directory has the following structure:

```
my-datascience-project/
    ...
    notebooks/
    ...
    projectmnemonic/
        projectmnemonic/
            __init__.py
            test.py
        setup.py
    ...
```

The `setup.py` is very plain (there is no intention to publish it):

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="projectmnemonic",
    version="0.1", 
)
```

I install the package in an activated anaconda environment as follows

```bash
pip install -e path/to/my-datascience-project/projectmnemonic
```

but get the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: <redacted>
Obtaining <path to my-datascience-project/projectmnemonic>
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: <projectmnemonic>
  Running setup.py develop for <projectmnemonic>
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    × python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [6 lines of output]
        running develop
        C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        error: --egg-path must be a relative path from the install directory to <projectmnemonic>.
        [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
    running develop
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    error: --egg-path must be a relative path from the install directory to <projectmnemonic>.
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

When I move directory `projectmnemonic` to the Desktop and install from there, I have no issues in the installation procedure:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: <redacted>
Obtaining <path to my-datascience-project/projectmnemonic>
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: <projectmnemonic>
  Running setup.py develop for <projectmnemonic>
Successfully installed <projectmnemonic>-0.1
```

Python 3.9.12, setuptools 67.6.1, pip 21.2.4

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the editable installation `(-e flag)` and your directory structure.

First modify the `setup.py` file to include the `packages` parameter

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="projectmnemonic",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

then go to projectmnemonic `cd path/to/my-datascience-project/projectmnemonic` then install your package properly `pip install -e .`

edit: If it still dont work we gonna try to update `setuptools` pip, first `install --upgrade setuptools` then go to our directory `cd path/to/my-datascience-project/projectmnemonic` and install it `pip install -e .` then `pip install .` ( you can also try with -e flag again here )

Comment: Appreciate your thoughts. Unfortunately, the problem persists with the same error message.

Comment: I modified the solution in my answer

Comment: please note that the installed version of `setuptools`, 67.6.1, as per my original post is the [up to date version](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#history)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem using a library. Usually I follow some steps, before installing a lib.

1: Check the versions of the libraries you are using, if they are compatible with your version of python.
Example:
lib: requests version (0.1) your python version 3.11. A very old version a very modern one
2: Upgrade pip `bash pip install --upgrade pip`

3: Install `bash pip install wheel`

Looking at your code structure, I understood that you are creating a package within the same project, that you want to use these tools, I imagine that importing within the notebook should work, but creating a setup should be in a separate project from what you intend to use.

I looked at the Python documentation, this reference might help more [docs python](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Comment: Unfortunately, your comment did not resolve my issue. Note that my conda environment is a fresh setup with the most recent version of (standard) packages, including `wheel`. I understand that this is an uncommon setup, but my ultimate library of interest is `my-datascience-project` and creating the "package" `projectmnemonic` is merely a mean to allow for imports (our IT forbids permanent changes to the python path and I don't want to manually add a path in every shell before I startup Jupyter notebooks).